# Azure AD SCIM Attribute Mapping - Group Membership Expression

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, expression, scim

I would like to create an expression for SCIM attribute mapping in Azure AD to pass a value to an attribute of the receiving application based on the user membership to a specific AD group.

The below expression, for example, passes value `New` to the attribute `userType` of the receiving application if the value of the Azure AD attribute `user.department` equals to `hr_new`, and passes the value `Old` if not.

`IIF([department]="new_hr", "New", "Old")`

See example settings below:

[image]

However, I haven't been able to query or check the group membership of a User in an expression in Azure AD. I would like to create an expression that checks if the user is member of group `abc` and if `true` it should pass the value `X` and if `false`, it should pass the value `Y`

Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As advised by @ZollnerdMSFT, querying AD Group membership directly using Expressions is not possible at the moment in Azure. The solution was to use **App roles**. I added new App roles to the enterprise application in Azure and then assigned the desired app role to each Group. Users within the AD Group(s) inherit the app role assigned to the Group(s) they belong to.

These inherited **App roles** can then be queried using Expressions. I then wrote an Expression to get the app roles that the user inherited and returned the desired value based on the app roles the user has - which implicitly reflects the user's Group membership(s).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at this time. Group membership is considered a property of the group object, and cannot be called into any logic expressions for user objects.