# How to map Azure User Groups to Salesforce Permissions Sets (or PS Groups) & Public Groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, salesforce, provisioning, scim

We have Azure AD sync'ing user accounts to Salesforce - this is working fine. In Salesforce we have a few custom 'Profiles'. And in Azure AD > Enterprise Apps > Salesforce > Users & Groups, we have AD Groups mapped to these profiles https://i.stack.imgur.com/W42cG.png

Due to additional development in Salesforce, we are now making use of a few Permission Sets (and Permission Set Groups), as well as Public Groups.

Rather than manually managing assignments to these various groups when new users are provisioned, I would like to automate it, based on Azure AD group membership.

I have read a bunch of threads on this topic. One suggesting the way to do this is to create an new App Role ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377887/azure-ad-scim-attribute-mapping-group-membership-expression) - see comment by Mike-S122). This is done via App Registrations > Salesforce > App Roles. So I created an App Role, which shows up when in Enterprise Apps > Salesforce > Users & Groups - I can click 'Add user/group', select the new Role in the list, and assign an AD Group, but if I try to provision-on-demand a user, I get an error that the user cannot belong to two groups. That makes sense.

Perhaps I need to edit the provisioning mappings instead? My current mapping looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnhJG.png).